# what are all the possible ways to insert a array in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a JSON array of occurrences, which occurrence contains a date, a value and a quantity, so:

```
[["May 09 2014",1.17,63],["May 10 2014",1.01,171],["May 11 2014",1.56,87]]
```

I need to insert this information in a MySQL database using a stored procedure, so I'm wondering what are all the possible ways to achieve this:

1. php loop (but each list can have up to 200 occurrences)
2. Parse a XML string inside the stored procedure
3. create some crazy logic to parse a string inside the stored procedure

is there another way?

Comment: You tagged this with php - Does your stored procedure already exist? A loop in PHP on the `json_decode()`'ed values would  be straightforward. Where does XML fit into this?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I could pass a big xml string to the MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

First, create PHP array from JSON:

```
$jsonString = '[["May 09 2014",1.17,63],["May 10 2014",1.01,171],["May 11 2014",1.56,87]]';
$array = json_decode($jsonString);
```

Now loop that array, generate inserts and write everything in single go. 200 entries are not so much to loop.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `tableName` (`data`, `value`, `quantity`) VALUES ";
$inserts = [];
$params = [];

foreach ($array as $index => $row) {
    $inserts[] = "(:data{$index}, :value{$index}, :quantity{$index})";
    $params[] = [
        ":data{$index}" => $row[0],
        ":value{$index}" => $row[1],
        ":quantity{$index}" => $row[2],
    ];
}

$sql = $db->prepare($query.implode(', ', $inserts));
$sql->execute($params);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a loop. `json_decode()` it and loop over it, inserting into MySQL. No need to do 200 requests though, you can grow one single large INSERT request by connecting new and new parts to it and then run it just once at the end. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

The code would be:

```
$arr = json_decode($arr);
$data = [];
foreach($arr as $a) $data = "('".$a[0]."',".$a[1].",".$a[2].")";
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO tbl_name(a,b,c) VALUES". join(',', $data));
```

You can also store it in plain JSON form in a text field.
Depending on circumstances sometimes it's the best solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode()` for decoding the json string.

```
$json = '[["May 09 2014",1.17,63],["May 10 2014",1.01,171],["May 11 2014",1.56,87]]';
$occu_array = json_decode($json);
```

Now you can iterate this array and insert the data rows into the database.

---

Iteration can be done in three ways:

1. Commit an insert for every item in the array.
2. Build one sql with one insert command for all items and commit this single sql.
3. Build one sql with multiple insert commands, one for each item, and commit this single sql.

Comment: An array of occurrences can have up to 200 items, maybe running each of them separately can crash the application?

Comment: @lolol 200 items should't be a problem at all. You can also build a sql with all rows and commit this single sql.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL can be build up with one code line without iterations:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ' . substr(strtr(trim($json), '[]', '()'), 1, -1);
```

The json string must be in `$json`. Consider that there is no conversion of the data type.